# Html table not taking up full width of window

Tags: html, css, html-table

All of my other tables seem to take up the full width of the window, as I would like them to, and I can't figure out why this one isn't. The html seems to be the same as the other tables. I think the error is occurring within the  element but when looking at it it seems to be set up properly. The code below is the code for the first table on the page in the screenshot.
[Screenshot of table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KZP1n.png)

```
<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-primary">
  </nav>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-justified" id="auth-tabs" role="tablist">
          <li class="nav-item"><a href="#users" id="active" class="nav-link  users" role="tab" aria-controls="users" aria-selected="True" data-toggle="tab">
          Users</a></li>
          <li class="nav-item"><a href="#groups" id="" class="nav-link groups" role="tab" aria-controls="groups" aria-selected="false" data-toggle="tab">
          Groups</a></li>
          <li class="nav-item"><a href="#scopes" id="" class="nav-link  scopes" role="tab" aria-controls="scopes" aria-selected="False" data-toggle="tab">
          Scopes</a></li>
          <li class="nav-item"><a href="#navigation" id="" class="nav-link navigation active" role="tab" aria-controls="navigation" aria-selected="true" data-toggle="tab">
          Navigation</a></li>
          <li class="nav-item"><a href="#pages" id="" class="nav-link  pages" role="tab" aria-controls="pages" aria-selected="False" data-toggle="tab">
          Pages</a></li>
          <li class="nav-item"><a href="#permissions" id="" class="nav-link  permissions" role="tab" aria-controls="permissions" aria-selected="False" data-toggle="tab">
          Permissions</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="tab-content" id="auth-tabs">
        <div id="users" class="tab-pane fade" role="tabpanel" aria-labeledby="users">
          <div class='row'>
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <h4>Authentication
                    <small>Navbar</small>
                    <button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary pull-right" onclick="app.auth.navigation.new_nav()">
                        <i class="fa fa-plus">
                        </i>
                        Add to Navbar
                    </button>
                </h4>
                <hr>
                <div class="row">
                    <table class="table Navbar" id="navbar-table" width="100%">
                       <thead>
                          <tr>
                            <th></th>
                            <th>Id</th>
                            <th>Page id</th>
                            <th>Name</th>
                            <th>Icon</th>
                          </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                          <tr id="Navbar-7">
                            <td><button class="btn btn-link table-btn" onclick="app.auth.navigation.form({&quot;primary_key&quot;: 7})">
                                Edit
                                </button><button class="btn btn-link table-btn" onclick="app.auth.navigation.confirm_delete({&quot;name&quot;: &quot;srjys&quot;, &quot;primary_key&quot;: 7})">
                                Delete
                                </button>
                            </td>
                            <td>7</td>
                            <td>8</td>
                            <td>srjys</td>
                            <td>il;t7;t</td>
                          </tr>
                          <tr id="Navbar-2">
                            <td><button class="btn btn-link table-btn" onclick="app.auth.navigation.form({&quot;primary_key&quot;: 2})">
                                Edit
                                </button><button class="btn btn-link table-btn" onclick="app.auth.navigation.confirm_delete({&quot;name&quot;: &quot;Jtyed&quot;, &quot;primary_key&quot;: 2})">
                                Delete
                                </button>
                              </td>
                              <td>2</td>
                              <td>8</td>
                              <td>Jtyed</td>
                              <td>agrfds</td>
                            </tr>
                          </tbody>
                      </table>
                  </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</body>


body {
  background-color: #F5F5F5;
}

.account-wall {
    margin-top: 75px;
    padding: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
        padding-top: 20px;
    background-color: #fff;
    -moz-box-shadow: 1px 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    box-shadow: 1px 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

.form-control {
    width: 100%;
    height: 34px;
    padding: 6px 12px;
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 4px;
        border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
        border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.075);
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.075);
    -webkit-transition: border-color ease-in-out .15s,box-shadow ease-in-out .15s;
    -o-transition: border-color ease-in-out .15s,box-shadow ease-in-out .15s;
    transition: border-color ease-in-out .15s,box-shadow ease-in-out .15s;
}

.form-signin {
  max-width: 330px;
  padding: 0;
}

.buttons {
  padding-top: 10px;
}

.form-group {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.form-signin input[type="text"],
.form-signin input[type="password"],
.form-signin input[type="email"] {
    margin-bottom: -1px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
    font-size: 14px;
}

.small-link {
  font-size: 14;
}

.margin-top {
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.bounds-label {
  padding-right: 0;
}

.bounds {
  padding-left: 0;
  padding-right: 0;
}

.table-btn {
  padding-top: 0px;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
}
```

Comment: And styles are where?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Your table should take up the full width with that code. Could you please provide your existing CSS as well? We can't reproduce your problem without it. Please update your question so that it shows your **CSS**, thus forming a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For further information, please refer to the help article regarding [**how to ask good questions**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [**tour of the site**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) :)

Comment: Just a thought: did you intend to have a row inside of a row? The table is taking up 100% of the width of its parent, but it's parent is a nested row, not the original row or a div with a column/grid class.

Comment: I have added my css, but mostly I am using bootstrap classes.

Comment: @B.Scott I'm not 100% sure I've laid out the bootstrap row/column grid correctly, but that layout seems to work for all of my other tables.

Comment: @JessicaResnick There's likely something in the base bootstrap styles (that we can't see) affecting this. When I try your provided CSS/HTML in JSFiddle it appears to work fine (and is full-width). 

https://jsfiddle.net/7wm052z5/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is I gave my table a class of 'Navbar' for js reference purposes, but that is also the name of a bootstrap class.